# How to update documents having same value for a field in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b713280000000000000000"), "role" : "admin", "clientId" : ObjectId("598231980000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dff1a80000000000000000"), "role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598231980000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59077ea80000000000000000"), "role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598231980000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59305d280000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598231980000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5957ea280000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598231980000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59593ba80000000000000000"), "role" : "admin", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59821a280000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598228380000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598227fc0000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c1d0000000000000000")}
```

I need to find all the documents with same clientId value, and update the clientId with the value of_id of the document which is having role "admin"

For example:

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("59593ba80000000000000000"), "role" : "admin", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59821a280000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598228380000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000")}
```

These 3 having same clientId, I want to update the clientId with the _id of document whose role is "admin" among these 3.

Then after update, the result will be:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59593ba80000000000000000"), "role" : "admin", "clientId" : ObjectId("59593ba80000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59821a280000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("59593ba80000000000000000")},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598228380000000000000000"),"role" : "user", "clientId" : ObjectId("59593ba80000000000000000")}
```

Comment: try to use moongose http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: i need to run the query in shell

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12

Comment: If you want help, please update your sample with valid ObjectId's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to run an aggregate operation that has a pipeline which first groups the documents by the `clientId`, within the group create an array of at most 2 elements i.e. the root document's `_id` if its role is `"admin"` and a constant value, say 0 if otherwise.

The next pipeline will filter the documents from the previous pipeline and return those which have more than one count for the above group.

The preceding pipeline step will then flatten this array to return denormalised fields in your documents and then filter the denormalised fields to only have the document that has the role "admin" `_id`. On executing this pipeline, use the cursor to iterate the results and update your collection.

The following example demonstrates the above:

```
var cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$clientId",
            "docId": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": ["$role", "admin"] },
                        "$_id",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
    { "$unwind": "$docId" },
    { "$match": { "docId": { "$ne": 0 } } }
])

cursor.forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.update(
        { "clientId": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "clientId": doc.docId } }
    );      
})
```

---

For very large collections, you could use **[`initializeUnorderedBulkOp()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/)** for updating your collection in bulk as this can significantly speed up performance as the writes are all done once on the server without the round trip

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;

cursor.forEach(function(doc){
    bulk.find({ "clientId": doc._id }).update({ "$set": { "clientId": doc.docId } });

    counter++;  // increment counter for batch limit
    if (counter % 500 === 0) { 
        // execute the bulk update operation in batches of 500
        bulk.execute(); 
        // Re-initialize the bulk update operations object
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    } 
})

// Clean up remaining operation in the queue
if (counter % 500 !== 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

Comment: Thank you @chridam

Comment: @Sabreena No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Try this!

```
db.dbName.find({clientId:"bbbbb", role:"admin"}).forEach(function(doc){   
    doc.clientId = doc._id;
    db.dbName.save(doc); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

db.sameValue.find({"clientId" : ObjectId("598b6c180000000000000000"),"role" : "admin"}).forEach( function(obj) {obj.clientId= obj._id;db.sameValue.save(obj);});